# how to get a single weights file in tensorflow js converter

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I'm using this command:

```
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model,'jsmodels')
```

but I get a model.json and 3 weights file

```
group1-shard1of3.bin
group1-shard2of3.bin
group1-shard3of3.bin
```

and I want to get only one .bin file, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not too sure if this is possible using `save_keras_model` but from the command line with `tensorflowjs_converter` I would do the following. Where you specify the `--weigth_shard_size_bytes` to be the size of the model you have. If your model is <= 30Mb then setting it to `30000000 bytes` will result in a single file `group1-shard1of1.bin`.

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras --weight_shard_size_bytes 30000000 'model.h5' 'output_dir'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because your model is over the the default size of 4mb. Hence, it is broken into multiple chunks of at most 4mb so set `weight_shard_size_bytes` argument of the `tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model,name_of_folder)` to a size larger than the size of your model, so you get just one `group1-shard1of1.bin` file.

```py
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model,name_of_folder,weigth_shard_size_bytes=1024*1024*size > than model_size)
```